# Creating Hash Code and Overflow

Tags: c#, hashcode

I am trying to generate a hash code from two integer inputs.  The approach outlined in

[Combining Java hashcodes into a "master" hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2943347/141172)

seems to work well for many input values.  However, when one of the input integers is `int.MinValue`, the behavior seems less than ideal.  Specifically I observe

```
int.MinValue * 1013 == int.MinValue

int.MinValue * 1009 == int.MinValue
```

but

```
int.MinValue * 2 == 0

int.MinValue * 20 == 0
```

All of this is in an *unchecked* context.

I would naively (and wrongly) assume that `int.MinValue * (something other than 1 or 0)` would yield a new bit pattern different than `int.MinValue` or `0`.

Questions

1. Why does multiplying `int.MinValue` by these constants yield `int.MinValue` (2 cases) or `0` (2 cases)?
2. Does the behavior of `int.MinValue` indicate a flaw in the hash algorithm?

Comment: It *might* indicate a flaw in *that* hash algorithm, but not all hash algorithms are implemented with only multiplication. In fact, take a look at how .NET usually does it, by adding in one prime number and multiplying with another. The addition might indicate a fix for this "flaw".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: It seems this method of creating a hash is considered flawed relative to other alternatives.  A Rotating Hash seems like a more appropriate choice http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplication is more or lest shift of bits to left. Since `int.MinValue` is `0x80000000` (only one highest bit set) multiplication can produce only two int values - 0 (if multiplying by even number ) or value with highest bit still set (for odd numbers).

Sample for 4 bit numbers (x,y,z - any value for particular bit, `1000` is equivalent of `int.MinValue` )

```
1000 * xyz1 =
   (xyz0 * 1000)  + 1000 * 1 = 
   (xyz  * 10000) + 1000 * 1 =  
   (xyz  * 0)     + 1000 = 1000

1000 * xyz0 = 
   (xyz  * 10000) + 1000 * 0 =  0
```

Comment: So this means that for prime P if P * inputValue < int.MinValue (when looking at arbitrary precision results), the final result would be int.MinValue (when looking at Int32 results), since P must be odd for P > 2?  This seems to indicate a large number of hash collisions for values near int.MinValue.  Would it be better to perform the math in a `long` then cast back to `int` before returning a hash value?

Comment: I'm not good with probabilities nor hashing expert, so I can't say how serious the problem is. To me it feels not very common - you either hash once (and should get random distribution) or combine multiple hash values - getting all hashes to be close to int.MinValue don't feel very likely. I've added "hashcode" tag so there are more useful related questions - check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595/what-is-a-good-hash-function?rq=1 as it seem to have reasonable discussion/links on hashing in general.

Comment: I think for my purposes, the edge cases will not matter.  For general purposes, I learned that this method of combining hashes is not very good and would use something more like a Rotating Hash http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx