# How does a set determine that two objects are equal in dart?

Tags: dart

I don't understand how a set determines when two objects are equal. More specific, when does the `add` method of a set, really adds a new object, and when doesn't it act a new object, because the object is already in the set ?

For example, I have objects from the following class:

```
class Action {
  final Function function;
  final String description;

  Action(this.function, this.description);

  call() => function();

  toString() => description;
}
```

Now I would think that the following set would contain 2 elements, as 2 of them are equal:

```
void main() {
  Set<Action> actions = new Set()
    ..add(new Action(() => print("a"), "print a"))  
    ..add(new Action(() => print("a"), "print a"))
    ..add(new Action(() => print("b"), "print b"));
}
```

But instead, this set contains 3 `Action` objects. See the [demo](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/9e516a3bb50a2610347d). How can I make sure that equal objects are seen as equal in the set ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For a comprehensive write-up about `operator==` in Dart see http://work.j832.com/2014/05/equality-and-dart.html

It just checks if they are equal `a == b` You can override the `==` operator to customize this behavior. Keep in mind that also `hashCode` should be overridden when the `==` operator is overridden.

```dart
class Action {
  @override
  bool operator==(other) {
    // Dart ensures that operator== isn't called with null
    // if(other == null) {
    //   return false;
    // }
    if(other is! Action) {
      return false;
    }
    return description == (other as Action).description;
  }

  // hashCode must never change otherwise the value can't
  // be found anymore for example when used as key 
  // in hashMaps therefore we cache it after first creation.
  // If you want to combine more values in hashCode creation
  // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26648915/217408
  // This is just one attempt, depending on your requirements
  // different handling might be more appropriate.
  // As far as I am aware there is no correct answer for
  // objects where the members taking part of hashCode and
  // equality calculation are mutable.
  // See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/217408
  int _hashCode;
  @override
  int get hashCode {
    if(_hashCode == null) {
      _hashCode = description.hashCode
    }
    return _hashCode;
  }
  // when the key (description) is immutable and the only
  // member of the key you can just use
  // int get hashCode => description.hashCode
}
```

try at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/dd4b8153518469e2f68a)

Comment: The argument to `operator==` is never `null` since `null` is checked explicitly before calling `operator==`. You can remove the `other == null` check.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! This wasn't what I remembered but it's even more comprehensive.