# Dart Stream / List

Tags: list, filter, stream, dart

I want to add a User into my List if there is no user with that name yet. Actually I generally want to avoid duplicates.
As I didn't find something like myList.distinct(User.name) or something like that I did it with a for for loop and if else:

```
myList.add(customUser);
for (User user in myList) {
  if (user.name == customUser.name)
    myList.remove(user);
}
```

I was just wondering if there is a smarter way to solve this in dart for example with a stream. But I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Set` instead of a list. A set only stores unique values.

For this if your values are custom class instances (`User`), your `User` class needs to implement `operator ==` for a `Set` to work properly.

For more details see [How does a set determine that two objects are equal in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567322/how-does-a-set-determine-that-two-objects-are-equal-in-dart/29567363#29567363)

Comment: Both "==" and "hashCode".  If ever one, then always the other.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz you are right of course. The linked question should provide this information and more.

Comment: Yeah, I had that beaten into me from my Smalltalk days.  I was using the ST80 image in 1982 and 1983. :)