# Flutter: testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, dart, flutter

I was trying to test this function

```
  UserApi createUserApi(String url, String username, String password) {
    UserApi userApi = new UserApi(base: route(url), serializers: repo);
    userApi.base.basicAuth('$username', '$password');
    return userApi;
  }
```

basically, the test was to compare the result of this function with a "manually composition" of it, expecting to have the same result. But It doesn't:

```
  String username = "asd";
  String password = "asd";
  UserApi userApiTest = new UserApi(base: route("asd"), serializers: repo);
  userApiTest.base.basicAuth('$username', '$password');
  test("UserApi creation", () {
    UserApi userApi = _presenter.createUserApi("asd", "asd", "asd");
    expect(userApi, userApiTest);
  });
```

The result is always :

```
Expected: <Instance of 'UserApi'>
  Actual: <Instance of 'UserApi'>
```

Why are they different? In the debug every property is the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two different instances of `UserApi`. Them having the same property values does not make them equal.

You would need to implement `hashCode` and `operator==`.
By default only comparing the references to the same instance of an object are considered equal (because they are identical)

See also

- [How does a set determine that two objects are equal in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567322/how-does-a-set-determine-that-two-objects-are-equal-in-dart)
- http://pchalin.blogspot.com/2014/04/defining-equality-and-hashcode-for-dart.html
- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html
- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/String/operator_equals.html

Comment: Sorry, if I ask a stupid question, but so I should override the == method in the class that I want to test?

Comment: If you want meaningful results for `==` with instances of your custom classes, then yes, you need to override `operator ==` and `hashCode`.

Comment: `expect(userApi, userApiTest);` is executed as `expect(userApi, equals(userApiTest));` which uses `==` to check equality. So your test is fine besides the missing `operator ==` and `get hashCode => ...`

Comment: yes, I've just tried. I had also some other problems, but now it works. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Thats really sad that a new language has to do all this ugly code manually to simple compare 2 objects. Any modern language allows to compare objects.

Comment: No matter how you design a programming language there will always be advantages and disadvantages. This one is a disadvantage that you get when you design a strongly typed language that produces small and fast executables as it is mandatory for web and mobile.

Comment: I also think that there is no point of overriding `operator ==` and `hashCode` just because of the tests. This can also have a side-effects in your "regular" code. Why don't you implement (or let your IDE implement) `toString` method in `UserApi` class, and then compare like this: `expect(userApi.toString(), userApiTest.toString);` ?

Or just "manually" compare every `UserApi` property individually.