# Dart indexWhere performance

Tags: dart

I want to search index where `fb3` is.
I have two options `indexA` and `indexB` like so.
Is there any performance differences like A is faster than B or vice versa?
Is there any better way to search `fb3`?

```
class Foo {
 String id; //unique
 int number;
 Foo(this.id, this.number);
}

class Bar {
 String id; //unique
 int number;
 Bar(this.id, this.number);
}

class FooBar {
 Foo foo;
 Bar bar;
 FooBar(this.foo, this.bar);
}

void main() {
  final Foo f = Foo('First Id', 18);
  final Bar b = Bar('Second Id', 81);
  final FooBar fb = FooBar(f, b);

  final Foo f2 = Foo('Third Id', 900);
  final Bar b2 = Bar('Fourth Id', 009);
  final FooBar fb2 = FooBar(f2, b2); 

  final Foo f3 = Foo('Fifth Id', 789);
  final Bar b3 = Bar('Sixth Id', 987);
  final FooBar fb3 = FooBar(f3, b3);  

  final Foo f4 = Foo('Seventh Id', 222);
  final Bar b4 = Bar('Eighth Id', 666);
  final FooBar fb4 = FooBar(f4, b4);

  final List<FooBar> fbs = [fb, fb2, fb3, fb4];

  final int indexA = fbs.indexWhere((FooBar fb) => fb.foo.id == fb3.foo.id && fb.bar.id == fb3.bar.id);
  final int indexB = fbs.indexWhere((FooBar fb) => fb == fb3);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Foo`, `Bar`, and `FooBar` do not implement `operator==` and `get hashCode` then `indexB` will only find identical instances.

```
var a = Foo('Fifth Id', 789);
var b = Foo('Fifth Id', 789);
var c = a;
print(a == b); // false
print(a == c); // true
```

See also [How does a set determine that two objects are equal in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567322/how-does-a-set-determine-that-two-objects-are-equal-in-dart/29567363#29567363)

There won't be any performance difference worth mentioning if `operator ==` is implemented. If you actually only want to find identicial instances then `indexB` would be faster, but then it would be better to use

```
(FooBar fb) => identical(fb, fb3)
```